# htaccess query string conversion

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL structure:

```
http://example.com/file.php?section=sectionName
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
http://example.com/file/sectionName
```

Current attempt appears not to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ file.php?section=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and appears to interfere with another rewrite which is stripping `.php` endings from filenames:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

#rewrite /file => file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]
#rewrite /file/foobar => file.php?section=foobar
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/?$ /file.php?section=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, I still get `http://example.com/file.php?section=sectionName`.

Comment: What url are you going to?

Comment: It's not a public URL, local in test environment.

Comment: Re1)do you mean "when you type "/file/foobar" you get redirected to "/file.php?section" ?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, this works entirely as it should. Apologies.